# Pyqt5 не запускается designer, но раньше работал

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, python-3.8

В обще пользовался спокойной pyqt5 и в один прекрасный день он не запустился. . .
Не запускается. не показывая даже никакой ошибки, переустанавливать пытался, а также пытался переносить папки platforms и bin, в общем - все, что советуют в интернете.

**Python 3.8**

библиотеки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

designer запускаю через Pyside2, но также пытался через pyqt5-tools, он писал чтобы я попробовал переустановить программу.